# Input pole to second order system generates forced response

Tags: control

Could someone explain to me in more detail what they mean in the highlighted line:

[image]

[control systems engineering by Nise]

**What is the constant forced response here referring to?** In this case, the total response will be the some (coefficients multiplied by the system natural terms) + (some DC constant value). The coefficients and the DC constant value will be defined by the input pole and the system pole valuse.

However, in this case, the total response is = the forced response/zero-state response since the system TF assumes zero initial conditions. The total response (= forced response) in this case just happens to look like the natural response of the system as we are applying a step in.

Answer (score 2):

The step response is the inverse Laplace transform of \$\frac{1}{s}G(s) \$ where \$G(s)\$ is the plant transfer function.

You have \$C(s) = \dfrac{9}{s(s+7.854)(s+1.146)} \$ which converted into a partial fraction gives

$$C(s) = \underbrace{\frac{1}{s}}_{\text{step}}+ \underbrace{\frac{0.170}{s+7.854}-\frac{1.170}{s+1.146}}_{\text{system}} $$

Taking the inverse Laplace transform of \$C(s)\$ will give you the step response for \$G(s)\$. Recalling that \$\mathscr{L}\{X_1(s) + X_2(s) \}^{-1} = \mathscr{L}\{X_1(s) \}^{-1} + \mathscr{L}\{X_2(s) \}^{-1}\$ yields

$$\mathscr{L}\{C(s)\}^{-1} = \mathscr{L} \bigg\{\frac{1}{s} \bigg\}^{-1} + \mathscr{L} \bigg\{ \frac{0.170}{s+7.854}-\frac{1.170}{s+1.146} \bigg\}^{-1}=1+0.170e^{-7.854t} -1.170e^{-1.146t} $$

As the author mentions, the response caused by the step-input is constant while the response caused by the system poles are decaying exponentials.

The **forced response** is referring to the system's response to the **forcing function** \$X(s) = \frac{1}{s} \$ (aka the step input).

Comment: But the system's response to the forcing function (1/s) is both the fixed constant AND the exponential decaying terms (natural terms). If I never applied a 1/s forcing function, then we wouldn't see the fixed constant nor the decaying exponential terms. So shouldn't the total response (fixed + exponential) in this case be called the forced response?

Comment: @AlfroJang80 The system's *impulse response* is given by the inverse Laplace of G(s) and, if you'll calculate it, you'll see that it is made of exp(-t) terms. It's the *integration* (of the impulse response, or multiplication by 1/s in frequency domain) that gives the step response and adds the constant term, since this is a lowpass and the step function is really just a constant after t=0.

Comment: I understand but I'm still a bit confused about what to label as the forced response and what to label as the natural response. Also, if the system had initial conditions, how would that be represented in the s-domain? Would it somehow be included in the T.F.?